# std::arg returns an incorrect value for real inputs (using MSVC compiler)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to do some simple phase calculations in C++ and discovered that I was sometimes getting the wrong results from `std::arg` when using real values as input.

According to the documentation on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/arg):

> Additional overloads are provided for float, double, long double, and all integer types, which are treated as complex numbers with zero imaginary component.

However this does not seem to be the case, because these two calls return different results.

```
auto x1 = std::arg(std::complex<double>{ -1.0, 0.0 });
// x1 = PI (3.14159...)

auto x2 = std::arg(-1.0);
// x2 = 0
```

Did i just find a bug in the MSVC implementation of the standard library, or am I missing something obvious?

**Compiler info:**

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.21.27702.2 for x86

Comment: It's MSVC baby, I get the same problem, so you might be on to somenthing.

Comment: If you look at the MSVC code someone messed up badly. There's a bit of macro nonsense but basically it's hard coded to return zero on a real argument.

Comment: I just upgraded to the latest Visual Studio version (16.5.4) and it's still the same.

Comment: Yeah it looks like @john is right. It looks like the implementation of arg for real numbers is just hardcoded to return 0. At least I think I'm looking at the right source file: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bug report and it turns out there was a bug in the MSVC standard library. It has been resolved now as of VS 2019 16.7 Preview 2!